# Response with non-OK status does not respect content-type in producer annotation

Tags: jersey, jackson, jersey-2.0

I encountered an odd while I was using Jersey..
I had the @Producer (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) for the whole resource class.
I have one class CustomerResponse, which is just normal)
If I return Response.status(Stauts.OK).entity(customerResponse).build(), on the client side, I will receive the json entity as I expected.
However, if I return Response.status(Stauts.BAD_REQUEST).entity(customerResponse).build(), the content-type become text/html.

If I change the Producer to APPLICATION_XML, the same thing happens. It seems to me that only response with 400 will return with content-type specified in the @Producer annotation. For all responses with other status code, it will simply return text/html.

Can anyone help me on this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This is turns out to be really interesting.
I started grizzly servlet instead grizzly server by using following code

```
WebappContext webappContext = new WebappContext("GRIZZLY Web Server WebappContext");
ServletRegistration servletRegistration = webappContext.addServlet("JerseyServletContainer", ServletContainer.class);
servletRegistration.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.packages", WebServiceConstants.ROOT_PACKAGE);
servletRegistration.addMapping("/*");
webappContext.deploy(grizzlyWebServer);
startGrizzlyWebServer(grizzlyWebServer);
```

It seems like the servlet somehow convert the content-type for all non-OK (not 400) http response to type=text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1.

If I started the grizzly-http-server, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

We use like the following:

```
Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(myObject)
            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).build()
```

Comment: Sure. But my way should work as well. Indeed, it does work. It seems like it has something to do with the Jersey client. If I use curl, all responses with JSON content type. However, if I use Jersey client, it seems like jersey client converts the content-type to text/html for non-OK response. However, I have not figure out how to  remove the override.